# How to control what subview comes on top in IB?

Tags: interface-builder

Suppose my view contains an image and a button. I'd like for the button to show up on top of the image? How can this be done as part of the Interface Builder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the xib file viewer, the view farthest down will be on top, the view highest up will be on the bottom. You can drag the views around to adjust their z-order.

[image]

Comment: I can't seem to find it, can you provide an example?

Comment: Sure pard. Click on the xib file in xcode, that window should pop up.